# Google Charts fetching from Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to create charts using Google Charts Api. My data is stored as a json file as shown.

```
    {
        "1":[{"a":0,"d":0}],
        "2":[{"a":0,"d":0}],
        "3":[{"a":6,"d":62.92}],
        "4":[{"a":1.57,"d":75.32}],
        "5":[{"a":1.67,"d":66.45}],
        "6":[{"a":1.25,"d":76}],
        "7":[{"a":1.36,"d":75.08}],
        "8":[{"a":1.59,"d":69.27}], 
...
    }
```

I'm fetching json file, pushing the objects to a javascript array. It works with no problem.  I added these lines to understand what's happening. However Google Api doesn't accept my values and shows only

```
dots.push([5, 50]);
dots.push([7,60]);
```

Here's my code

```
function drawDots()
{  
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'a');
    data.addColumn('number', 'd');

    dots = new Array;
    dots.push([5, 50]);
    dots.push([7,60]);

    $.getJSON("/graph/graph.json", function(json)
    {
        $.each(json, function(id, num)
        {
            $.each(num, function(i, e)
            {           
                dots.push([e.a, e.d]);
            });
        }); 

    });

    data.addRows(dots);

    var options = {
        title: '',
        hAxis: {title: 'Data 1', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
        vAxis: {title: 'Data 2', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
        legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);  
}
```

Data type of the values are number, I also tried eval() to. In console, values are seems in array. Can't understand what's wrong.

Here's the console log of dots and data with a screen shot.
[image]

Comment: I've quickly put your code into a jsfiddle and it appears to be working fine, are you sure there's a problem?

Comment: @winseybash Yes I'm pretty sure. I edited the question and added a ss. Values from json is present in the dots array however they are'not passing to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the asynchronous getJSON call.  The getJSON call happens but while it's still retrieving the contents of `graph.json`, the rest of the code executes.  This means that the getJSON callback runs after the chart has been drawn.

Solution: Move the chart drawing code into the getJSON callback:

```
function drawDots()
{  
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'a');
    data.addColumn('number', 'd');

    dots = new Array;
    dots.push([5, 50]);
    dots.push([7,60]);

    $.getJSON("/graph/graph.json", function(json)
    {
        $.each(json, function(id, num)
        {
            $.each(num, function(i, e)
            {           
                dots.push([e.a, e.d]);
            });
        }); 

        data.addRows(dots);

        var options = {
            title: '',
            hAxis: {title: 'Data 1', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
            vAxis: {title: 'Data 2', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
            legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Makes sense :) Thanks!